# Hapi.js reply.redirect() is not working after image upload

Tags: hapi.js

I have the following code, in my server. I'm uploading an image using mongoose and s3 and then want to redirect the user to another page but this isn't happening. (the upload is successful).

Routes.js:

```
{path: '/success',  method: 'GET', config: controller.success} ......
```

controller.js:

```
imageUpload: {
        payload: {
                maxBytes: 209715200,
                output: 'file',
                parse: true
            },
        handler: function(request, reply) {
            var userName = request.auth.credentials.username;
            members.findMemberByUsername(userName, function(err, member){
                if (err) {
                    return reply.view('upload', {error: err});
                } else if (member) {
                    var IDImagePath = request.payload.uploadedIDname.path;
                        console.log(IDImagePath);
                    members.addID(member, IDImagePath, function(err1){
                            console.log("add id error", err1);
                        if (err1){
                            return reply.view('upload', {error: err1, member: member});
                        } else {
                            console.log("SUCCESSFUL!");
                            return reply.redirect('/success');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    },

    success: {
        handler: function (request, reply){
            request.auth.session.clear();
            console.log("success handler working!!");
            return reply.view('success');
        }
    }
```

The code hits both `console.log("SUCCESSFUL") and console.log("success handler working!!")` in the controller but the redirect doesn't take place. By the way I'm using 'Jade' as the templating language so I have a `success.jade`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. I'm using AJAX on the client side but didn't have a 'success' method to reload the page:

```
$('#submitID').click(function(){
var formData = new FormData($('#uploadID')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/image',
    type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){ 
            console.log(myXhr.upload);

        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    success: function(data) {
        window.location.href = "/success"
    },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
}, "json");
});
```

I needed `window.location.href = "/success"` to reload the page. Please note the jQuery Ajax SUCCESS method is different to my '/success' route, they just happen to be the same word.

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem, you should close the question as it already solved.